# Web-based screensharing applications that works with MacOS 10.5 Leopard?

Tags: leopard, screen-sharing

Using MacOS 10.5 Leopard, I want to be able to share my screen with others during a meeting so the people I'm talking to can easily see my screen through a web browser. A free solution would be preferable.

I looked at [Join.me](http://join.me/), [ReadyTalk](http://www.readytalk.com/), and [AnyMeeting](http://www.anymeeting.com/), but none of those work with MacOS 10.5. Skype's screensharing *does* work, but (a) recipients need Skype (vs. just a web browser), and (b) I don't think you can do one-to-many sharing for free.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Screenleap](http://www.screenleap.com/)? I'm not sure which versions of Mac OS it supports, but it's worth a try.